# htaccess RewriteRule without RewriteCond not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

Why does this work:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

But if I remote the `RewriteCond` it doesnt work and I get an internal server error.

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

If I modify the `RewriteCond` e.g. like this it doesnt work too.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

I want to redirect **all** requests to app.fcgi. I dont want the user to be able to access files directly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is giving you internal server error (500) because without `RewriteCond` your loop is infinitely looping.**

You can use this rule to prevent this:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!app\.fcgi/).*)$ /app.fcgi/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!app\.fcgi/)` is a **negative lookahead** that prevents this rewrite rule to execute if request is already `/app.fcgi/`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Why did you add the `nocase` flag (`NC`)? Is it important?

Comment: `NC` is not important here actually. It is just that I had used `(?!app\.fcgi/)` in pattern and you may also want to match `(?!APP\.fcgi/)` for example.